# Can't upload raster file on PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, imagery, postgis-raster

I've been trying to upload my satellite imagery which is 1.5 GB to my PostgreSQL database,  using the code below, the error for each command is stated below;

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -t auto -F -I -C -Y '.\Ceva I Ra 2020.tif' public.Ceva2020 | psql -d MB_database -U postgres

raster2pgsql -s 4326 -t auto -F -I -l 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256 -C -Y '.\Ceva I Ra 2020.tif' public.Ceva2020 | psql -d MB_database -U postgres

Program 'psql.exe' failed to run: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program. At line:1 char:109
+ ... Ceva I Ra 2020.tif' public.Ceva2020 | psql -d MB_database -U postgres
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.

At line:1 char:1
+ raster2pgsql -s 4326 -t auto -F -I -l 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256 -C -Y '. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```